OpenGL direct to framebuffer on Pi Zero 2 (no Qt, no X11)?
I spent the past while trying to google for an answer to this, but I keep running into Qt-related solutions.
I’d like to write some OpenGL ES code to output to a connected HDMI display. It should fill the full display, no windows, etc.
I'm having trouble finding the right keywords or technologies to look at. I think I need linuxfb. But I can't even figure out how to install that. And I can't find sample code showing how to configure OpenGL ES to write to the framebuffer (let alone how to get a shader to work).
Any suggestions on what to look for?
Bonus points for how to play back video.
